# One user has multiple uids with omniauth facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I implement omniauth and facebook plugin with devise for login system.

However, it seems the same facebook account will return different token `uid`,

How could I handle the kinds of situation in Rails.

Does my new designed method has bad side effect ?

I'm planing to use only facebook omniauth as the only way to login my system.

## Original create user method

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
end
```

## The new designed method

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(email: auth.email).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
end
```

## Sample documents

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55bf803b69702d0603000000"),
  "email": "sample@gmail.com",
  "encrypted_password": "5a2U.62pm6.fsdfdsfdsvNrf.akZ4la45ixpgqB20n6uu",
  "sign_in_count": 4,
  "provider": "facebook",
  "uid": "113569521332134112514",
  "reset_password_token": null,
  "reset_password_sent_at": null,
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("55c157a5506f638652000000"),
  "email": "sample@gmail.com",
  "encrypted_password": "$sdfgg,so51lkpe7P5DDKwz3hTrqFE7MsfRw0lEa",
  "sign_in_count": 1,
  "provider": "facebook",
  "uid": "10000014141261376741",
}
```